# Making a Table Using !htbp?

Tags: errors

```
 LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\title {Something}
\author{Something}
\date {Due October 12, 2016}
\maketitle
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
-insert something here-
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
[(P \ensuremath{\vee} Q) \ensuremath{\wedge} (P \ensuremath{\rightarrow} R) \ensuremath{\wedge} (Q \ensuremath{\rightarrow} R)] & [(P \ensuremath{\vee} Q) \ensuremath{\wedge} (P \ensuremath{\rightarrow} R) \ensuremath{\wedge} (Q \ensuremath{\rightarrow} R)] \ensuremath{\rightarrow} R   \\ \hline
True & True  \\ \hline
False & True\\ \hline
True & True \\ \hline
False & True \\ \hline
True & True \\ \hline
False & True \\ \hline
False & True \\ \hline
False & True \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\pagebreak

\textbf{Exercise 2} \\

\textbf {Exercise 3} \\

\textbf {Exercise 4} \\

\pagebreak

\textbf {Exercise 5} \\

\textbf {Exercise 6} \\

\pagebreak

\textbf {Exercise 7} \\

\textbf {Exercise 8} \\

\textbf {Exercise 9} \\
\end{document}
```

Here are the basics. What is this error trying to tell me?

Comment: You don't need to show us the table, but it helps if you include what you think should compile (from `\documentclass` through `\end{document}`), so that we can copy and paste what you're trying to do and immediately start tinkering.

Comment: Is the `table` environment maybe embedded inside another environment? Please advise.

Comment: Okay, editing example now.

Comment: Seems like you are opening `\begin{table}` but never close them

Comment: also as stated in your earlier question using `\\ ` at the ends of paragraphs like this is completely wrong and will generate multiple (real) warnings.